# How to integrate AWS SNS push notification with Firebase in Angular 7 with C# as API

Tags: c#, typescript, firebase, angular7, amazon-sns

In my Angular 7 web application i want to integrate AWS SNS push notification with firebase.Where i am having messaging and alerts notification functionality.So for that i want to update notification when ever there is new notification in DB for that there is job where he can track for that but that is further discussion.
I have refer this link https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1
But getting error of - Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.I am troubleshooting this but not getting solution.

Can anyone help with any related documentation or any other link where i can refer.

Comment: Hello everyone, can any one tell me how can i upgrade notification count dynamically using any method.I am using angular 7 and API is in C#.i.e if there is new entry for notification in DB then it should be updated to UI.Is using SignalR a good option?